# How Do I Code To Prevent Intermittent net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from Chrome Browser

Tags: c++, multithreading, google-chrome, synchronization, iocp

The bug I'm seeing is intermittent.

First, the codebase.

1. The repo is [here](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/tree/reentrant1)
2. Where I think the bug is coming from is [here](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/reentrant1/iocphttpl/SocketCompletionPortServer.cpp)
3. I think [GetQueuedCompletionStatus()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets blocked because of thread synch issues?

Debugging the code, I made a screenshot of it, you can see the network tab showing one file having the stalled status.

It's not always one file stalling, that's just one case. Other cases, one another file would stall.

What should I be thinking of here? Should I be adding mutexes in there?

[image]

Comment: Update: I've added mutexes in the several places and also made it do an exit(1) when it goes in error. Also ran a couple test on IE, screenshot shown when you click the URL: http://postimg.org/image/62ii11t8d/

Comment: Update #2: In Google Chrome, I switched to Incognito mode and disabled the cache. I still get stalled loads but a lot less than compared to the previous testing. See screenshot by following the link: http://postimg.org/image/425ev9cfj/

Comment: Update #3: I learned a lot iterating through test runs, until the bug finally showed up. Turns out, there is a handshake that I was not aware not, how web browsers make calls to the server. I learned that the hard way. Anyway, the fix is posted [here](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/reentrant1/iocphttpl/SocketCompletionPortServer.cpp) and the [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/e4pm996s9/) comparing how fast IE and Chrome with respect to fetching and loading. Based on the numbers, IE is the faster client for this server.

Comment: Update #4: Additional bug fixing resulted to better performance on Chrome. [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ttj7hqo19/) showing the bug fix and deeper understanding of the handshake for IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error intermittently when trying to start debugging,

below are the things I have done

- Firstly, cleared the cache, cookies, etc from the browser. The issue was still there.
- Then I noticed that my system was running with very low disc space, So removed unnecessary stuff, emptied the recycle bin, etc. Even this had not fixed the issue
- Finally, as I had not shut down the system for more than a week, I have shut it down completely and restarted. And the issue has been resolved.